# Why Consumer or Supplier argument needs {} for multiple annotations

Tags: java, lambda, option-type

Let's say there's an `Optional` optString. Now if I use it as below:

```
optString.ifPresent({
    //some statements
    }, () -> throw new Exception());`, it fails to compile.
```

Why do I've to wrap the `throw new Exception()` inside curly braces `{}`.

Why can't I simply do `() -> throw new Exception`.

Why is the compiler treating `throw` and `new` as some states that should be in a block?

In IntelliJ it fails with compilation errors: `expected ) expected { expected;` and `Unexpected token`

A complete example:

```
class OptionalTest {

    Optional<String> testString() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
    
    void getString() {
        var optStr = testString();
        optStr.ifPresentOrElse(s -> {
            
        }, () -> throw new RuntimeException());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post full example

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: IMHO, the tags `optional` and `java-8` are more than relevant because `optional` addresses the problem with an appropriate method choice and `java-8` the version of Java (the available methods differ across versions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply `throw` in the lambda expression the way you did since a lambda body is either a single expression or a block. The `throw` is a statement.

You have to wrap throwing an exception into the block:

```
optStr.ifPresentOrElse(
    str -> /*do something*/,
    () -> { throw new RuntimeException(); });
```

It is also worth mentioning `Optional#orElseThrow` which is designed to actually throw an exception. The only argument passed into the `Supplier` is the way to instantiate the exception, the method just takes it and throws instead of you if the `Optional` is empty.

```
optStr.orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException());
```

Comment: So what is the equivalent of `optStr.ifPresent( /*do something*/).orElseThrow();`

Comment: @Mohammad Ah, I get your question. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Side note: when the Java designers worked on the new `switch` syntax, they considered it too annoying to wrap `throw` statements in braces, so they added a syntactic exception, so you can write, e.g. `switch(someString) {  case null -> throw new RuntimeException("is null");  case String s -> /* do something with s */ System.out.println(s);  }`. But I don’t know of any plans to allow the same for lambda expressions.

Comment: @Holger: Do you have any sources? I would like to read more about it.

Comment: The syntax is in [the language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11.1); as you can see, there are the alternatives `SwitchRule:
SwitchLabel -> Expression ;
SwitchLabel -> Block
SwitchLabel -> ThrowStatement`. My example used even newer syntax which JDK 17 only provides as [preview feature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/preview/specs/patterns-switch-jls.html#jls-14.11).